# How to do Stateful retry with spring kafka batch listener

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm reading through the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#retrying-deliveries and I cannot figure out what the correct way is for implementing stateful retry with a batch listener

The docs say that a "retry adapter is not provided for batch message listeners because the framework has no knowledge of where in a batch the failure occurred".

This is not a problem for my use case as I want to just retry the whole batch.

The docs recommend that I use a RetryTemplate within the listener itself. Ok, I can do that.

The problem comes in the next section where it discusses using the stateful retry flag to make the consumer poll between retries in order to prevent the broker from dropping my consumer.

How do I configure a batch listener to do that? Is the stateful retry flag supported for batch listeners? If My retry logic is in within the listener itself, wouldn't that prevent the polling? What exactly does the statefulRetry flag even do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of spring kafka has a special RetryingBatchErrorHandler. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh Thanks, Spring Kafka Team!

Comment: And the upcoming 2.5 release has the [RecoveringBatchErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.RC1/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh) where the listener can throw a special exception to tell the error handler which record failed and the ones before it are committed and not replayed. The release candidate [is available](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-5-0-release-candidate).

Answer (score 1):

No; you can't add a `RetryTemplate` to the container factory for a batch listener.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter cannot be cast to org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener

[We will clean that up with a more meaningful error.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1219).

With the upcoming 2.3 release (release candidate currently due next Friday) [you can add a `BackOff` to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1185) which provides similar functionality to the `RetryTemplate`; with current releases, the redelivery will be attempted immediately.

Furthermore, another new feature [recently merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/cc1e19b6b0c1d3b8e36b534ac7276509459b9869) provides a mechanism to retry from a specific index in a batch.